# How do I generate the first 12 numbers in the sequence 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9 using a while loop?

Tags: java

I have figured out the formula to work the sequence out which is the use the each number in the sequence uses the previous previous previous number + the previous previous number for example to get the number 4 you use the previous x3 number which is the first 2 in the sequence plus the previous x2 number which is the second 2 in the sequence. I understand that I have to use 4 variables and then swap the number accordingly in the loop but i cant quite figure out how to do so.
Here is what I have so far.

```
    System.out.print("Loop for the first 12 terms of sequence 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9\n");
            int p0, p1, p2, p3, c;// c in control p is num is sequence.
            c=0;
            p0=1;
            p1=1;
            p2=1;
            p3=p0+p1;
            while(c<=12){
                System.out.print(p0+","+p1+","+p2+","+p3+",");
                c++;
            }
```

which just gives me the first 4 numbers of the sequence 12 times. Do I have to use an entirely different while loop for the next numbers or can I do it in the same loop?
any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That’s because your loop doesn’t do anything else than print four numbers. You’ll have to add some code to change the values if you expect things to change

Comment: Hint:  read about the [Rubber Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) debugging technique.  Seriously.

Comment: That is called the Padovan sequence: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/padovan-sequence/

Comment: which is why I said this is what I have got so far...

Comment: [I downvoted because there was no effort to debug the code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this code. This will give you your result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int limit = 12;

    int value1 = 1;
    int value2 = 1;
    int value3 = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        if(i == 0) {
            System.out.println(value1);
            System.out.println(value2);
        }
        System.out.println(value3);

        int temp = value3;
        value3 = value1 + value2;
        value1 = value2;
        value2 = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: considering the level of the question, it could be a good idea to explain a little bit, the OP will basically copy/paste, do his homework like it probably is, and understand nothing, then come back in SO for next trivial no-effort topic..

Comment: While it's not strictly against the rules (AFAIK), giving homework answers is a huge disservice to the posters. For people that will actually end up in software, it deprives them of what they went to school for, and for people who really have no interest, deprives them of the knowledge that they should choose another path. This problem *should* have been a fun exercise.

Comment: @TerryCarmen It's not against the rules of SO. Homework questions aren't disallowed either, but they do still have to follow the same rules as other questions. But yeah, it's not encouraged, especially if it's in the style of "do my entire homework"

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

Initiate an array of 12 numbers

Enter the starting sequence in the array(you have 10 numbers in your sequence)

Give to your iterating variable index of the last number in the sequence

Apply your formula and find the value

Increment the value of your iterator

All can be done inside one while loop no need for another. Also make sure not to get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`